# En Python, ¿como puedo pasar los datos numéricos de un archivo txt a una variable para ir almacenandolos en dicha variable?

Tags: python, archivo, variables, csv, texto

soy novato en python y agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda para seguir avanzando en este paso en el que me he quedado clavado.

El tema es el siguiente, tengo un archivo txt en el cual se van agregando valores, el formato es asi:

---

Fecha: 17 de 01 del 2023 --- Combinacion:  ['1', '4', '17', '12', '56', '46']

Fecha: 17 de 01 del 2023 --- Combinacion:  ['2', '5', '18', '32', '66', '86']

Fecha: 17 de 01 del 2023 --- Combinacion:  ['1', '9', '10', '22', '36', '46']

### Fecha: 20 de 01 del 2023 --- Combinacion:  ['5', '18', '30', '38', '41', '48']

Pues bien, mi intencion es que desde el programa recopile SOLAMENTE los numeros  que figuran despues de "Combinacion", y que los vaya almacenando como enteros en una variable, pero la verdad es que no doy con ello, agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda (se aceptan risas, lo entiendo).

Os pongo parte del codigo que tengo hecho para esta tarea:

## LEER ARCHIVO DE TEXTO

def leer_archivo():
sleep(4)
os.system("cls")

```
Almacenados = []

with open("Bonoloto.txt") as archivo: 
    for datos in archivo.readlines():

        Almacenados.append(datos[-36:])  # Print(linea[-36:]) # Lee a partir del caracter 35 
                                         # contando desde atras

os.system("cls")            
print(Fore.YELLOW + "\nNumeros Almacenados hasta el momento:")
print("------------------------------------- \n")  
print(Fore.GREEN+ Style.BRIGHT + "".join(Almacenados))
```

leer_archivo()

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: No tengo idea de si tenés control de como se genera el archivo, pero si tenés el control y no es necesario que se vea tal y como lo muestras, es más recomendable que cambies el formato del archivo a uno más facil de entender por la maquina (como por ejemplo, un csv o un json, que incluso Python tiene un modulo en la librería estandar para procesarlos) antes de hacer un parser complejo que, ante el lenguaje natural, puede tener fallos.

Comment: he de hacerlo de este manera, pero no doy con ello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código transforma cada línea del archivo en una lista de enteros:

```
with open("comb.txt", "r") as combinaciones:
    for linea in combinaciones:
        _, lista = linea.split("Combinacion:")
        lista = lista.strip().replace("'", "")[1:-1]
        valores = [int(x) for x in lista.split(",")]
        print(valores)
```

Cada línea del archivo de combinaciones la dividimos en dos partes, antes y después de la palabra "Combinacion:". La primera parte la descartamos y la segunda la guardamos en `lista`:

```
 ['1', '4', '17', '12', '56', '46']
```

Ahora hay que limpiar la variable eliminando los espacios al principio y al final con `strip()`. También eliminamos las comillas usando `replace()` y los `[]` usando rebanada de listas, lo que nos deja **una cadena** con el siguiente contenido:

```
1, 4, 17, 12, 56, 46
```

Para convertir la cadena en una lista de enteros, primero la dividimos donde haya comas y luego tomamos la subcadena y le aplicamos `int()` para llevarla a entero. Todo eso va dentro de una comprensión de listas; el resultado es una lista de enteros:

```
[1, 4, 17, 12, 56, 46]
```

#### Demo

La ejecución produce:

```
[1, 4, 17, 12, 56, 46]
[2, 5, 18, 32, 66, 86]
[1, 9, 10, 22, 36, 46]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu rápida ayuda, lo he entendido perfectamente, ahora voy a probarlo

Comment: de todos modos, me aparece el siguiente error, y no entiendo el por qué, coloco el código tál como indicas, es decir:

Comment: El error que da es el siguiente según tú código:                                                              _, lista = linea.split("Combinacion:")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Candid Moe no tuvo en cuenta en su respuesta las lineas vacias. Entonces, cuando el split se encuentra con una linea vacía, devuelve una lista de un solo item: "\n" ("\n" es el caracter que representa la separación entre dos lineas), y claro, como intenta sacar 2 items de una lista de uno solo, da error. Lo que hago habitualmente en esos casos es quitarle a la linea los espacios que le rodean y luego, si el resultado de eso está vacío, considero la linea como "vacía" y la salto.